# Dynamic allocation of array in C, when reading a file with lines of unknown data length

Tags: python, c, arrays

I've got a maybe simple question. I have to transform some python code to c, and I am not that experienced in c.

I am looping through a file in python reading it line by line. If there is a certain token in the line, I have to split it and read the values into a int array. This array is then used for further processing. An example of a file is given here:

```
Event   163
Time    29-05-2013, 11:41:45
TDC1.HEX_B  927532 1460340
TDC1.HEX_F   -1
TDC1.HEX_x1 930080 1462311
TDC1.HEX_x2 929198 1462611
TDC1.HEX_y1 1462957
TDC1.HEX_y2 928628 1462151
TDC1.HEX_z1 929097 
TDC1.HEX_z2 930314 1462992
TDC1.Trigger    1728347
errors  0 0 0 0
proc_time   40
%
Event   500
```

Now my problem is that i don't know many integers there will be in each line. In python I can do something like this:

```
if 'TDC1.HEX_B' in line: 
    numbers_str = line.split()[1:] # use all the words except the first
    B = [ float(x) for x in numbers_str ]
```

Where B in this example, will be a list where the length corresponds to the count of numbers in the numbers_str. Is there a similar possibility in c to allocate an array which just is long enough? I have to loop over the array later on, when processing the data. I have read about malloc() and realloc(). Do they help? And if so, is there a good resource to read about them? Do I maybe have to read the line first, and then malloc an array for the number of ints in that line?

Comment: I'd suggest reading a book about C before trying to write C code... The stuff you're asking seems to me like basic C coding.

Comment: @ErikAllik: What a pointless comment!

Comment: Also consider whether it is really worth coding this in C. Perhaps there is a way to read the data with Python script, and then hand over the actual processing to C for speed up (because, unless you have thousands of lines in your file, and you need to execute it thousands times, you won't get any profit from coding this part in C; and even then, it may be fast enough in Python).

Comment: Right now I have 500 files with approximately 2000 lines in each, that is why I want to switch to c. I was also looking at ctypes..

Comment: A quick test on my machine takes half a second to read 500 such files with 2000 lines. That's not the slowdown and really not worth the pain of toying with malloc/realloc, so you might want to consider doing the I/O in Python, and then storing `B` in binary format or a database format. You could then find a convenient way to read `B` in your C program that will do the actual, slow, computation ("convenient" meaning that you know in advance how many floats `B` is, e.g., store the length of `B` as well).

Comment: consider reading to a buffer with `char *fgets(char *buf, int size, FILE *stream)` and manipulating it with `char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);`

Answer (score 2):

If you can use C++ you might find a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) easier to use. If you must stick to C you can malloc an array at some initial size and use an int to keep track of its size and how full it is. Then every time you add to the array check if you are about to overfill it, and if you are, then realloc it to make its capacity larger (x2 each time for example).

Some code:

```
int initialSize=2;
int size=initialSize;
int nElements=0;
int* myArray=malloc(initialSize*sizeof(int));

//Do some line-by-line parsing

//Found a token
int token; //You set this

if(nElements==size)
{
    size=size*2;        
    myArray=realloc(myArray, size*sizeof(int));
}

myArray[nElements]=token;
nElements++;
```

Answer (score 0):

`malloc()` and `realloc()` are what you need if you don't know how big an array you need. Use `malloc()` to allocate the memory at the start. Keep one variable with the size of currently allocated memory, and another with the number of values stored so far. When you have stored the maximum number of values, use `realloc()` to get a larger area of memory.